# Bundling Realm with App and Migration

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm, realm-migration

I am following the Realm documentation on migration and on bundling a realm with an app.

I am using the following code to copy the bundled Realm to be the default Realm. which works well.

```
let initialURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bootstrap_v001", withExtension: "realm")!
let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!

if Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.schemaVersion == 0 {
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(defaultURL)
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(initialURL, toURL: defaultURL)
    } catch {
        // Handle error here
        print("realm delete copy error!!")
    }
}
```

This all works OK and I can see the correct Realm file which has data in it. However, if I use realm = try! Realm(), the results that it returns are always empty.

It should be noted that I have the following declaration at the top of AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
let uiRealm = try! Realm()
```

I'm not sure if this initial global declaration of uiRealm is causing the issue. I have tried declaring local versions as well, but this doesn't seem to fix it.

It should be noted that if I re-run the application when the Realm file is already in place things are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying that `uiRealm` instantiation at the top of your delegate. I'm pretty sure that would be what's causing the issue.

Realm caches internal copies of its `Realm` instances, so it's extremely important that if you're moving any files around on disk, you do so before you create any `Realm()` objects (Or do any Realm operations where `Realm` instances are created,  encapsulated in an `@autoreleasepool`).

In this case, you should make sure that `uiRealm` is first touched only after you've done your initial file setup.